# how to upload file using Angularjs, multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i want to upload image using Angularjs anyone know how do this..REST API wants

> Content-Type:multipart/form-data

```
www.abc.com/images/id
Request Body
{
    // --Boundary_1_1626119499_1392398808202
    // Content-Type: image/png
    // Content-Disposition: form-data; filename="ducky.png"; modification-date="Wed, 05 Nov 2016 19:53:17 GMT"; size=713915; name="upload_image"        

    // {binary data truncated for display}
}
```

my Question is how to upload image file using above rest API, how to assign  $scope.tempObject = my Upload image Path

```
 $scope.UploadImage =  function () { 
        var config = {headers:  {      
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

       }
        }

    $http.post(properties.customerUploadImage_path + "/"+checkprofile,$scope.tempObject,config).success(function (response) { 
 Console.log('Uploaded');
    });


    }
```

Comment: use Content-type : undefined

Comment: Hi, you should consider using this lib. It really did the trick for me :) https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't use `$http` the right way.

You can use the `headers` attribute of the `$http` service, like this :

```
$scope.UploadImage = function () { 
  var config = {
    headers: {      
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    }
  };

  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: properties.customerUploadImage_path + "/" + checkprofile,
    data: $scope.tempObject,
    config: config,
  }).success(function (response) { 
    console.log('Uploaded');
  });


};
```

I suggest you to take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Answer (score 1):

Configure the headers with `"Content-Type": undefined` and use the FormData API:

```
  var config = { headers: {
                   "Content-Type": undefined,
                  }
               };

  vm.upload = function() {

    var formData = new $window.FormData();

    formData.append("file-0", vm.files[0]);

    $http.post(url, formData, config).
     then(function(response) {
      vm.result = "SUCCESS";
    }).catch(function(response) {
      vm.result = "ERROR "+response.status;
    });
  };
```

Normally the AngularJS $http service uses `Content-Type: application/json`. By setting `Content-Type: undefined`, the framework will omit the Content-Type header and the browser will use its default content type which is `multipart/form-data` for FormData objects.

**Request Header**

```
POST /post HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 388298
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://run.plnkr.co
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 Chrome/55.0.2883.54 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9lBDT4yoh8lKWtIH
Referer: https://run.plnkr.co/cW228poRVzWs67bT/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

**Request Payload**

```
------WebKitFormBoundary9lBDT4yoh8lKWtIH
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file-0"; filename="Crop.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundary9lBDT4yoh8lKWtIH--
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/S642uACPAaVFMrGYmRwD?p=preview).

For more information see,

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference -- Setting HTTP Headers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers)
- [MDN Documents -- FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)