# Angular file upload to PHP backend

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, angular-http

I'm developer and I try to learn some of AngularJs, now i try to do a form, and is necessary send a file from input[file] to php, but when I click the buttom the file is not sended to this php, Try with some examples, but none worked.

Regards!!

my code:

```
<form>
    <input type="file" file-model="csvFile" name="contactFile" on-read-file="showContent($fileContent)" class="filestyle glyfecha glyphicon input-sm" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" ng-click="sendForm()" style="margin-top: 10px;margin-bottom: 10px;">Guardar contactos</button>
</form>


app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                console.log(element[0].files[0]);     //this work
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);

app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post('v1/contact/upload/0', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response.data);
    })
}
}]);

app.controller('addcontacto', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){
$scope.sendForm = function() {
    var file = $scope.csvFile;
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file);
};
}]);
```

Comment: (1) Put a `console.log('hello')` inside your `app.controller` code. Does it appear when you load the web page? (2) Is there more this file you haven't shown? Eg, I don't see `ng-app` or `ng-controller` anywhere, I wanted to confirm if you omitted them from the example intentionally.

Comment: @therobinkim thank, but i can see the "hello" , I omitted intentionally the files ,ng-app and  ng-controller

Comment: What is purpose of `headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}`?

Comment: @guest271314 I copy it directly from tutorials, in several I have seen that write it like this

Comment: Can you include `php` at Question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to upload file using Angularjs, multipart/form-data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868451/how-to-upload-file-using-angularjs-multipart-form-data)