# Angular Js send Http (post)request with XML data

Tags: javascript, xml, angular

I should send HTTP post request to another server from my angular app :

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url:'www.example.com/SearchHotel.php',
data:
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Service_SearchHotel>
   <AgentLogin>
    <AgentId>xxx</AgentId>
    <LoginName>xxxx</LoginName>
    <Password>xxx</Password>
   </AgentLogin>
 <SearchHotel_Request>
  <PaxPassport>MA05110184</PaxPassport>
   <DestCountry>WSASTH</DestCountry>
    <DestCity>WSASTHBKK</DestCity>
     <HotelId InternalCode=""></HotelId>
      <Period checkIn="2017-10-26" checkOut="2017-10-28" />
       <RoomInfo>
        <AdultNum RoomType="Twin">2</AdultNum>
         <ChildAges />
       </RoomInfo>
        <flagAvail>Y</flagAvail>
   </SearchHotel_Request>
 </Service_SearchHotel>'
,
headers: { 
'Content-Type' :'multipart/form-data',
'Content-Disposition': 'form-data', 
**'name':"requestXML",**
'Accept':'application/xml',
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE',
'Access-Control-Allow-Headers':'Content-Type'
}
}).then(function(error,response){
if (error) {
console.log(error);
}else{
 console.log(response)
}
```

which requestXML is mandatory from servar on `google postman` data return as normal but in  my app always return  :

```
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>↵<Service_SearchHotel>↵  <SearchHotel_Response>↵    <Error>↵      <ErrorDescription>Invalid Tag XML</ErrorDescription>↵    </Error>↵  </SearchHotel_Response>↵</Service_SearchHotel>↵"
```

and give me `Invalid Tag XML` . how I should pass `requestXML` to my post data because Im sure its from this becuse before I add this part to postman its return me same error .
If any help will save me so much time

PS:
`'Content-Disposition': 'form-data', 
**'name':"requestXML",**` this part I copy from postman, before I try `'Content-Type' :'application/xml',` and data like : `data:'XML Request :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>........` and get same error

Answer (score 0):

Maybe take a look here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rest-assured/QPjllwl8ins

Essentially, you need to specify a content boundary and place that boundary at the beginning and end of `data`

```
$http({
method: 'POST',
url:'www.example.com/SearchHotel.php',
data:
'------MuhUniqueIdX8nBO7q27yQ1JNb
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Service_SearchHotel>
   <AgentLogin>
    <AgentId>xxx</AgentId>
    <LoginName>xxxx</LoginName>
    <Password>xxx</Password>
   </AgentLogin>
 <SearchHotel_Request>
  <PaxPassport>MA05110184</PaxPassport>
   <DestCountry>WSASTH</DestCountry>
    <DestCity>WSASTHBKK</DestCity>
     <HotelId InternalCode=""></HotelId>
      <Period checkIn="2017-10-26" checkOut="2017-10-28" />
       <RoomInfo>
        <AdultNum RoomType="Twin">2</AdultNum>
         <ChildAges />
       </RoomInfo>
        <flagAvail>Y</flagAvail>
   </SearchHotel_Request>
 </Service_SearchHotel>
------MuhUniqueIdX8nBO7q27yQ1JNb'
,
headers: { 
'Content-Type' :'multipart/form-data; boundary=------MuhUniqueIdX8nBO7q27yQ1JNb',
```

**Also take a look at using the AngularJS Form Data API, [how to upload file using Angularjs, multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40868451/how-to-upload-file-using-angularjs-multipart-form-data)**